# Realm configuration returns random schemaVersions, causing migration to fail

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

We are currently using Realm inside our app, but when I try to perform a migration (because we want to delete a Model/class in our database), the Configuration returns some random huge value from the `configuration.schemaVersion`.

The migration isn't called, and nothing is deleted. The Realm database was called multiple times with `let realm = try? Realm(configuration: Realm.compactConfiguration)`

I tried to make one Config throughout the app and set it like the following:

```
let configuration = Realm.compactingConfiguration
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = configuration
```

but the large schemaVersion still appears, and the code doesn't go inside the migrationBlock

```
extension Realm {

public static var compactConfiguration: Configuration {
    get {
        // Realm is compacted on the first open if the configuration block conditions were met.
        // Compacting when size is greater than 50MB (arbitrary amount, database size should be
        // around 2.6MB, so should not reach 50MB)
        let currentSchemaVersion: UInt64 = 1
        var configuration = Realm.Configuration(
            schemaVersion: 1,
            migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                if (oldSchemaVersion < currentSchemaVersion) {
                   migration.deleteData(forType: Office.className())
                }
            })
        configuration.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
        return configuration
    }
}
```

}

Does anyone know what is going on? I expected the versionScheme to be 0 since it was never set before.

Comment: At what point is it returning a large value for the schema version? Right after initializing? Also why do you have `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` set to true if you want the migration to happen?

Comment: @SanthoshR yes, it starts right at initialization, returns values like `4689` and `1994535`. the deleteRealm one is legacy code, not sure whether it should be deleted or not, but I commented it out before and it didn't make a difference when breakpointing the migrationBlock